# Rails 5.1 mailer error - account activation parameter in templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm following Mike Hartl's Rails tutorial & ran into an issue when creating email templates. (Please note the tutorial is based on Rails 5.0.1, while I'm plowing ahead with Rails 5.1.1.)

The tutorial uses **:activation_token** & **:activation_digest** attributes to handle the security risks of signup URLs, and a **:create_activation_digest** hook to set their values before creating the **User** model.

Here's the mailer view template:

`<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>`

The issue appears to be telling Mailer to use the value of **:activation_token** in the **:id** field of the route. (A URL definition error)

Here's the route definition, from `rails routes`:

```
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
```

The error feedback:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"test7@example.com", :format=>nil, :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
```

I've tried hard-coding id: @user.activation_token in the mailer template, to no avail.

This seems like a easy one, but I'm stumped and a little worried that I'm overlooking something hidden in the transition from Rails 5.0.x to 5.1.x. Any ideas?

Comment: Please check for `@user.activation_token` is it nil?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in your `config/routes.rb` file, you  GET    `/account_activations/:id/edit`. That makes it necessary to send an ID which you don't want/need to do. Now I know that [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#sec-account_activation_mailer) uses :id for token. But you're not defining `id:` in your link. So either you need to change the route, or change the link.

```
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(id: @user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

Notice I define `id:`. Normally outside this tutorial though, you should consider changing your route to `GET /account_activations/edit/:token` and then look up the user by token.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all,
But the error was related to how I defined the :activation_token hook in the User model. All tests now pass.

Comment: Hi Brian, Do you remember what you did wrongly as I am facing the same issue. Thanks.